# Is there a quadratic eqation with rational coefficients and a root $\cos(2\pi/5)$?

Tags: real-analysis

My friend Wolfram Alpha suggested that

$$
\cos(5x)=\cos^5(x)-10\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x)+5\sin^4(x)\cos(x)
$$

(This can be verified just expanding using addition rule OR using de Moivre's theorem etc..) So converting all $\sin$ terms using $1-\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x)$ would give me an rational coefficient equation with a root $\cos(2\pi/5)$, but is there a quadratic one too?

I fail to find any, using double angle formula doesn't give rational coefficient equation, and besides that I don't have much idea.

Any helps appreciated!

Comment: Once you have your equation, factor it to get a lower-degree equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\cos(2\pi/5)=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$.

We can see this by considering $p(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$. If $w=e^{2\pi i/5}$ then $2\cos(2\pi/5)=w+\frac{1}{w}$ and $p(w)=0$.

We can transform $p$ to $x^{-2}p(x)=x^2+1/x^2+x+1/x+1=(x+1/x)^2-2+(x+1/x)+1$

Therefore $w+1/w$ is a solution of $q(x)=x^2-2+x+1=x^2+x-1=0$.

To get a polynomial that has the half as root you can transform $q$ to $2^{-2}q(2x)$, or simply $q(2x)$ if you don't care about it being monic.

You get then the $$4 x^2+2 x-1=0$$

Comment: Thanks, thats very cool way of showing the value of $\cos(2\pi/5)$

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(2\pi/5)$ is a solution of $$4 x^2+2 x-1=0$$

Comment: Nice, could you explain how you verify this? Since unfortunately I can't see right away why this is true ( I believe it though)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\cos(2\pi/5)=\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{5}-1)$ (courtesy of your friend wolfram alpha).  If that is the root of a quadratic equation, it will factor like:

$(x-\cos(2\pi/5))(x-\text{something})$.  Just make the something, $\frac{1}{4}(-\sqrt{5}-1)$.  The factorization is $(x-\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{5}-1))(x-\frac{1}{4}(-\sqrt{5}+1))$.  Then just expand it out.

Comment: You can multiply by any non-zero constant (say 16 for example) and not change the roots.  If you multiply by 16, you'll get rid of those two 1/4 fractions and pick up a 4 in front of both x terms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider the polynomial $x^5 - 1$, which has a factor of $x - 1$; the quotient is irreducible and has a root $\zeta = \exp{\frac{2 \pi i}{5}}$. The field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ has a unique totally real subfield, generated by $\zeta + \overline{\zeta} = 2\cos(2\pi/5)$ and counting degrees shows you this field is quadratic. (Making this proof explicit gives the other answer and is a good exercise.)